# Binding the sum of an observableList of BigDecimals to a Label

Tags: java, javafx, binding

I need to get two specific fields of every object inside an ObservableList, multiply them and get the sum of all their products. I also need to keep the sum updated

For now I'm trying to get the sum of only one of those fields first (just because its easier and might help me to understand what is happening).

I have discovered:

- [How to bind an ObjectBinding<BigDecimal> to a Label with a Formatter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61855785/how-to-bind-an-objectbindingbigdecimal-to-a-label-with-a-formatter)

which is almost what I'm trying to do. However, applying the same code will throw a NullPointerException. Which I assume it's because there was more behind the scene.

Also, according to:

- [Javafx How to make a Binding to a list of Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46300540/javafx-how-to-make-a-binding-to-a-list-of-properties)

the observableList needs to have and **extractor** so it can track the updates of the required field on each element.

Here is what I tried, only ONE field first!!:

```
// Graphical stuff
void createExempleMenu(){

ObservableList<Itens> orc = FXCollections.observableArrayList(o -> new Observable[] {o.valueProperty()});
Label valueFinalLabel;

valueFinalLabel.textProperty().bind( // this gets NullPointerException
                Bindings.createObjectBinding(() ->{ 
                if(orc==null || orc.isEmpty())
                    return BigDecimal.ZERO; // case orc is empty
                else
                    return orc.stream().map(i->i.getValue()).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO,BigDecimal::add);},
                        
                orc).asString()
        );
}
```

---

```
// item
class Itens {
    private ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> value;
    public BigDecimal getValue() {
        return value.get();
    }
    public void setValue(BigDecimal b){
        value.set(b);
    }
    public void valueProperty(BigDecimal b){
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. including the complete stacktrace

Comment: I'm curious what the orcs are.

Comment: Wouldn’t this always just throw null pointer exceptions? You never initialize `value`.

Comment: Sadly, orcs were once elves, now imprisoned in an `ObservableList`; even so, their `valor` still requires a `BigDecimal`.

Comment: I'm sure there was actually a reason for me to name it "orc". It was 4 A.M tho, so I have no idea anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues with the `Itens` class:

- You never initialize `value`.
- The method `valueProperty(BigDecimal b)` must return
  `ObjectProperty<BigDecimal>` instead of `void`.
- You have a typo in method `getValue()`, instead of returning `value.get()` you are returning `valor.get()`.

```
class Itens {

    private final ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> value = 
            new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "value");

    Itens(BigDecimal value) {
        this.value.set(value);
    }

    public BigDecimal getValue() {
        return valueProperty().get();
    }
    public void setValue(BigDecimal value){
        valueProperty().set(value);
    }
    public ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> valueProperty(){
        return value;
    }

}
```

Also, you never initialize the `Label`.

Finally, you can improve your `Bindings`:

- You can create a `StringBinding` directly instead of creating an
  `ObjectBinding` and then creating `StringBinding`.
- `orc` is never `null`, so you don't need to
  check for `null`.
- You don't need to check for `orc.isEmpty()` because when you reduce
  the `stream` you are supplying an identity `BigDecimal.ZERO

```
Label valueFinalLabel = new Label();

ObservableList<Itens> orc = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        obs -> new Observable[] {obs.valueProperty()});

valueFinalLabel.textProperty().bind(
        Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> orc.stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(Itens::getValue)
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add).toString(), orc));
```

Test:

```
valueFinalLabel.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> 
        System.out.println(String.format("Label change from %s to %s", 
                oldVal, newVal)));

Itens i1 = new Itens(BigDecimal.valueOf(1));
Itens i2 = new Itens(BigDecimal.valueOf(2));
Itens i3 = new Itens(BigDecimal.valueOf(3));

orc.add(i1);
orc.add(i2);
orc.add(i3);

i1.setValue(BigDecimal.valueOf(4));
```

Output:

```
Label change from 0 to 1
Label change from 1 to 3
Label change from 3 to 6
Label change from 6 to 9
```

Comment: Thank you! That's much better than the first post I quoted. I've two questions though: 
What does `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` do? 
And what does the extractor did in this case? My code seems to work without it, but I don't know why

Comment: @Jão Schmidt If the `Stream<Itens>` contains any `null` value when you map using `.map(Itens::getValue)` it will throw a `NullPointerException`. To avoid that case I added `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` to filter all `null` `Itens`.

Comment: @Jão Schmidt If you don't use an extractor in the `ObservableList<Itens>`, the `Label` will only be updated when you add or remove `Itens`. But it won't be updated when you set a new value to any of the `Itens` contained in the `ObservableList`. In the answer, the last test `i1.setValue(BigDecimal.valueOf(4))` won't update the `Label` without an extractor and should not update using your code.

Answer (score 1):

Always remember to initialize your variable folks:

```
Label valueFinalLabel = new Label("some text");
```

I may write another question to ask about the product of two fields, which was my initial objective

Where is a complete sample for anyone who stumble here:

```
public class Main extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        
        ObservableList<Itens> orc = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        Label label = new Label("0.00");

        label.textProperty().bind( // this gets NullPointerException
                        Bindings.createObjectBinding(() ->{ 
                        if(orc==null || orc.isEmpty())
                            return BigDecimal.ZERO; // case orc is empty
                        else
                            return orc.stream().map(i->i.getValue()).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO,BigDecimal::add);},
                                
                        orc).asString()
        );
        
        Button btn = new Button("add stuff");
        btn.setOnAction(e->{
            orc.addAll(new Itens("1"),new Itens("2"),new Itens("3"),new Itens("4"),new Itens("5"));
        });
        
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label,btn);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
        primaryStage = new Stage();
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setWidth(200);
        primaryStage.setHeight(200);
        primaryStage.show();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
public class Itens {
    
    private SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal> value;
    Itens(String v){
        value = new SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal>(new BigDecimal(v));
    }
    public BigDecimal getValue() {
        return value.get();
    }
    public void setValue(BigDecimal b){
        value.set(b);
    }
    public SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal> valueProperty(){
        return value;
    }
}
```